# TypeError: response.postData is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

My code below gives the error "TypeError: response.postData is not a function".

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')

var url = ("https://www.adidas.com.tr/yeezy/product/GY1759")

function main(){
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
  puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.mouse.click(1000, 40);
    await page.on('response', response => {
      if (response.url() === "https://www.adidas.com.tr/rhsYl92ry/P4YX/xsLtQ/uJuJSkf31r/JGkkPDcC/QGBAD/nlbSQI"){
        console.log(response.postData())
      }
    });
  })
}
main()
```

I want to get the request's post data, how can I do that ?

Error = "TypeError: response.postData is not a function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of potential misunderstandings here:

1. `page.on` doesn't return a promise, it registers a callback that runs asynchronously upon the event firing. It's misleading to `await page.on` because it makes it seem like your code will wait for something, but it won't. You'd need to promisify the handler if you want your code to wait for it, or chain all code that depends on the result from the callback.
2. Doing `click()`, then `on()` is probably not what you want. Usually, you register the `on()` event listener, then trigger the event that fires the request you want to capture. Otherwise, the response might arrive before you get a chance to set up your `on()` listener.

Answering your main question, you can [access the original request on the response](https://pptr.dev/next/api/puppeteer.httpresponse.request) to get the post data: `response.request().postData()`. Note that this is form data only, not a JSON payload (adding a `"Content-Type": "application/json"` header and proper JSON body results in undefined -- see [issue #5178](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/5178) which shows that adding an `&& response.request().method() === "POST"` check avoids it triggering on the preflight OPTIONS request). You might also want to use `page.on("request", ...)` directly, but it's not clear what you aim to accomplish ultimately.

Since your code isn't working for me (a hard-coded coordinate click is very brittle; prefer making a selection, then clicking the element that you've targeted), I'll share a minimal, runnable example that you can extrapolate to your needs:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^19.6.3

const html = `
<body>
<script>
fetch("https://httpbin.org/post", {
  method: "POST",
  body: "foo=bar",
});
</script>
</body>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const responsePromise = new Promise(resolve => {
    const handler = response => {
      if (response.url() === "https://httpbin.org/post") {
        page.off(handler);
        resolve(response.request().postData());
      }
    };
    page.on("response", handler);
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  const postData = await responsePromise;
  console.log(postData); // => foo=bar
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Note that all of this is roundabout and mainly for illustrative purposes. A cleaner way is to use [`page.waitForResponse`](https://pptr.dev/next/api/puppeteer.page.waitforresponses) which doesn't require promisification like `on()` does:

```js
// same html and require as above

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse(response =>
    response.url() === "https://httpbin.org/post"
  );
  await page.setContent(html);
  const response = await responsePromise;
  console.log(response.request().postData()); // => foo=bar
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading into the [`Response` type definition for Puppeteer](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/puppeteer/v4/index.d.ts#L1072), it looks like you have other methods you can use.

Either `await response.json()` or `(await response.buffer()).toString()`